# why abstract property is lost in a subclass of Runnable interface?

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance, abstract, runnable

I am actually learning Threads. But get stuck with a very basic problem. I know if I inherit an interface in my class I have to give definitions of all the methods (mentioned in that interface) in my inherited class, else it has to be declared as abstract. Now I have tried very simple code...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


abstract class Code implements Runnable 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

    }
}
```

there was no problem in the compilation,and then I removed the `abstract` keyword from class code and it was showing me compilation error,saying class code is not abstract...

There has to be error. But then I did what ,checking some variation,extended Thread class also from class and recompiled the code. And I got no compilation error! Though I have not given the definition of `run()` method, neither I mentioned my class as abstract. 
there...

```
 class Code extends Thread implements Runnable 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {

    }
}
```

means this class lost the abstract property. How was that possible? Anyone explain please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,you know Runnable interface having only one abstract method. i.e,

```
abstract public void run();
```

If you are implementing Runnable you have to provide definition of run() method in your own concrete class or you can make your class abstract. Now you can provide the definition of run() method in your class explicitly,or implicitely by inheriting any other class having a valid definition of run() method. Thread class also has a valid definition of run() method. So, if you are inheriting both Thread class and Runnable interface in your class,that class is no longer carrying any abstract property.that is why you did not get compilation error.Make sure about the access specifier of run() method. If you are inheriting any other class instead of Thread you have to provide there concrete run() method as,

```
public void run()
 {
    //body
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Runnable` is an interface which requires any class that implements it to implement a `run()` method

```
public class A implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // implementation of run
    }
}
```

`Thread` is a concrete class that implements the `Runnable` interface.  That means it has concretely implemented the `run()` method.

```
public class Thread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // Java's implementation of run
        // for the Thread class
    }
}
```

When you define a class that extends `Thread` it means that it will be extending the `Thread` class which has already implemented everything required for the `Runnable` interface.  So you don't need to implement the `run()` method.  You can however `override` the implementation from `Thread` and optionally call it if you need to.

```
class A extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // implementation of run
        // optionally call super.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) is an interface containing just one method, [run()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html#run--), abstract as you pointed out. If you would implement the interface:

```
class A implements Runnable {
   ...
}
```

The compiler would complain: `Class A must be either declared abstract or implement abstract method 'run()' in 'Runnable'`, so as pointed by the error message you can choose to implement the method:

```
class A implements Runnable {
  public void run() {
     ...
  }
}
```

or make the class A abstract:

```
abstract class A implements Runnable {
}
```

any of the solutions would satisfy the compiler. Another solution would be make `A` an interface as well:

```
interface A extends Runnable {
}
```

All depends on what you would like to accomplish. For later of the provided solutions would be useful if you would like to extend the existing hierarchy but you don't want to have any state in **A**.

Answer (score 1):

[Runnable](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Runnable.java/?v=source) is an interface with below declaration.

```
public
interface Runnable {
    /**
     * When an object implementing interface <code>Runnable</code> is used
     * to create a thread, starting the thread causes the object's
     * <code>run</code> method to be called in that separately executing
     * thread.
     * <p>
     * The general contract of the method <code>run</code> is that it may
     * take any action whatsoever.
     *
     * @see     java.lang.Thread#run()
     */
    public abstract void run();
}
```

When you declare that your class with `implements Runnable` classue, ***either you have to implement run() method or declare your class as abstract***

When your class extends `Thread` with below statement

```
class Code extends Thread
```

The `Thread` class has already implemented `run()` method and hence you are not getting compilation error. You can remove `implements Runnable` from below statement, which is redundant.

```
class Code extends Thread implements Runnable
```

Have a look at [Thread](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java/?v=source) source code:

```
public
class Thread implements Runnable {

public Thread(Runnable target) {
    init(null, target, "Thread-" + nextThreadNum(), 0);
}

 public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class does not have to implement all methods from an interface. When you remove 'abstract' a Runnable class has implement the run method

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.Thread` already implements `Runnable` interface and defines `run` method. So when you extend `Thread` you already have all that is required to implement `Runnable`. You can, if you wish, override `run` method with your own definition. But you don't need to, if Thread's own implementation satisfies your needs.